# How to get referrer URL after a redirect in javascript

Tags: javascript

If you enter an invalid video id in YouTube (e.g. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXX) it will redirect you to a page saying it is a malformed video ID. Is there a way to get the original URL (in this example "http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XXX") in javascript?

(I'm talking about Javascript that will run on the browser after the redirect, through Firebug)

Answer (score 11):

You are looking for [`document.referrer`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_doc_referrer.asp).

Comment: No, if you try the scenario you will see that document.referrer is empty.

Comment: yeah just tested this doesn't work for the above case

Comment: @SitianLiu When i try this now there is no longer a redirect.  it stays on the page and shows the video unavailable message. 8 years ago this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `<meta>` tag in your codebase with these two attributes `name` and `content`,
i.e.:

```html
<meta name="referrer" content="always" />
```

This is how you can set the referrer value after a redirect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).